# Looking for alternative key stretching

Tags: bcrypt, scrypt, proof-of-work

I am by no means a security expert, but I am curious whether functions that don't produce different outputs when raised to the power of N (without any psuedo-randomness) exist, that are as strong as *"bcrypt"* or *"scrypt"*?

Comment: Could you make your requirements a bit clearer? Do you mean that $f(f(x)) = f(x)$?